# Textbox redirect on click

Tags: textbox

How do I make a textbox with a redirect on click when the user clicks in the text area (without clicking the sumbit button)?

```
 <form method="POST">
  <input id="textboxsearch" type='text' value=''>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Javascript. It would even be easier with the library [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#textboxsearch').click(function(){
            $('form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you have never worked with jQuery before, here a quick intro:

> jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes
>   things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling,
>   animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works
>   across a multitude of browsers. With a combination of versatility and
>   extensibility, jQuery has changed the way that millions of people
>   write JavaScript.

You can include it with their [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

But why do you want the user to be redirected, before he types in something?

Comment: Hi @Marc, i wanted to transfer the value of a textbox to another page with another textbox and auto sumbit the results without clicking...
but i was having trouble and i found the above solution to do it
do you have anything to suggest me for my first method?
(Your code is working fine but how can you add the url that makes it redirect?)

Comment: A form will "redirect" to the page you add as action `<form action="myOtherPage.html" method="post">` will redirect to `myOtherPage.html`.

Comment: What would the condition be to "auto submit"? For example when the user presses enter

Comment: i want on the second page after the value transfers from the first one to automatically show the results.

Comment: You can't do this with simple HTML (it's only a markup language). For this you will need PHP.

Comment: There is a good Basics example (it does almost exactly what you're trying): http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp